# I am getting a SSLHandshakeException and CertPathValidatorException error while using self signed certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate

I am trying to send a https request to apache2 which afterwards is recieved by Django. The code was working fine before ssl with http but now it is giving an exception. I just need to send a https request to django via apache2. My apache2 server is running on AWS server.

This is in my MainActivity.java file.

This is my hurlstack code

```
 hurlStack = new HurlStack() {

        @Override
        protected HttpsURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            Log.w("testing","in hurlstack exception ");

            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) super.createConnection(url);
            Log.w("testing","after url ");

            try {
                Log.w("testing","in hurlstack try ");
                httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
                httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w("testing","In hurlstack exception"+e.toString());
            }
            Log.w("testing","end of  hurlstack" + httpsURLConnection);
            return httpsURLConnection;
        }
    };

  private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
    Log.w("testing","In hostname verifier");
    return new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            //return true; // verify always returns true, which could cause insecure network traffic due to trusting TLS/SSL server certificates for wrong hostnames
            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
            return hv.verify(hostname, session);
        }
    };
}

private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
    Log.w("testing","In trust manager");
    final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    return new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    try {
                        if (certs != null && certs.length > 0){
                            certs[0].checkValidity();
                        } else {
                            originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                        }
                    } catch (CertificateException e) {
                        Log.w("testing", "certificate error "+e.toString());
                    }
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    try {
                        if (certs != null && certs.length > 0){
                            certs[0].checkValidity();
                        } else {
                            originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                        }
                    } catch (CertificateException e) {
                        Log.w("testing", "certificate server error "+e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    };
}

private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    Log.w("testing", " in ssl socket factory");
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.apache_selfsigned); // this is the file with .crt extension stored in \app\src\main\res\raw folder path
    Log.w("testing", "ssl socket");
    Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    caInput.close();

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

I have a MySingleton.java file

```
private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext(),new HurlStack());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {

//        getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
      req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

Command I used to create self signed certificate are

```
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out apache-selfsigned.crt -keyout apache-selfsigned.key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the certificate request file generated above and self sign it to generate the certificate file.

`openssl x509 -trustout -signkey apache-selfsigned.key -days 365 -req -in apache-selfsigned.crt -out apache-selfsigned.cer`